# Docker need /var/lib 777 permission

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm running docker with apache2. When doing docker-compose up -d it needs 777 permission to var/lib directory. If I give 777 permission then docker start but the same movement other application like Skype, sublime won't able to start and give an error like

cannot open cookie file /var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.sublime-text
/var/lib/snapd has 'other' write 40777

so here the problem is sublime need 755 permission but docker need 777 permission

Also, one of snaps file of docker is also available inside /var/lib/snapd/snaps

Due to this problem, I'm not able to simultaneously use docker and other application

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

app:
image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.13
ports:
  - 80:8000
links:
  - db
  - phpfpm
  - redis
  - elasticsearch
volumes:
  - ./.docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - .:/var/www/html:delegated
  - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:delegated
  - sockdata:/sock

 phpfpm:
image: markoshust/magento-php:7.1-fpm
links:
  - db
volumes:
  - ./.docker/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
  - .:/var/www/html:delegated
  - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:delegated
  - sockdata:/sock

db:
image: percona:5.7
ports:
  - 3306:3306
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
  - MYSQL_USER=test
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

redis:
image: redis:3.0

elasticsearch:
image: elasticsearch:5.2
volumes:
  - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
dbdata:
sockdata:
esdata:


# Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento 
(https://github.com/markoshust/docker-magento)
 # Version 12.0.0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that it needs 777 permission? Also can you post your compose file?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I have added compose file

Comment: Do you get an error when using the default permissions? Also you say `If I give 777 permission`, on what folder do you apply these settings and where?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of error https://clb.sh/ff798f If i give 777 permission to var/lib/* then docker start working but other application stop working

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this error about /var/www and not /var/lib?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I have reinstall the docker and disable apparmour to resolved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort But after disable apparmour my sublime not opening and giving error "warning: cannot open cookie file /var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.sublime-text
cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory"